# Cannot install ubuntu from usb

Tags: boot, usb

I tried to find a solution in other questions, but haven't find anything useful yet.
The problem is that, when i attempt to install ubuntu, (booting from usb and getting into the GRUB menu) the installer doesn't start and all the screen just gets black. The same usb is working fine on 2 other pcs.

I have noticed that it doesn't even show the logo of ubuntu with the dots, and the background is always black instead of the ubuntu's purple. 
Tried to leave it for like an half hour to see if something will change, but nothing gets better. My screen keeps telling me that i got signal from the hdmi port, then losing that signal, then have it again, but the screen is black all the time. I can provide Photos if needed.

Right now the only thing i have tried is to remake the usb installer (using rufus) in Iso and in DD mode. Both have the same problem.

Edit: After an hour in that i am trying to find a solution from the boot settings, i reched that: [image]

I think i got some kind of unsupported GPU.

I am using Palit RTX 2070 Super atm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Please tell us about the problematic computer: Brand name and model of the computer itself and also of the graphics chip/card. This will help us help you.

Comment: @sudodus the PC is made from parts, i assembled it myself. The GPU is RTX 2070 Super (Palit's one if that matters).

Comment: This is the GPU problem. Use `nomodeset` then install a driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a new and I think very powerful nvidia graphics card. Ubuntu understands, that it is nvidia, because it is trying with the graphics driver `nouveau`, but it cannot run it in graphics mode.

- Try with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`, and
- if that works, later on install Ubuntu, and
- boot the installed system also with `nomodeset`, and
- at this stage, try to install a proprietary graphics driver for this nvidia card.

It is most likely to work with the newest possible version of Ubuntu, 19.10, which comes with the newest linux kernel and its new versions of hardware drivers.

Comment: thanks, that worked. I just installed it on the ssd and it's booting fine now. The only problem i got is that the screen shows as a cube in the middle of the acreen, and doesn't spread till the corners. I guess this is due to the incompatible drivers. Anyways, thank you very much !

Comment: @AlexKalaidjiev, You are welcome :-) I hope that there will soon be a new version of the nvidia driver, so that you can use the full capacity of the graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the Secure Boot option from the BIOS.

Try to make the bootable drive with UNetbootin.

Comment: This is a wrong solution. Ubuntu installs with SB enabled.

Comment: But, can be in some other BIOS settings like Disabled "Boot From USB"... not wrong at all. Thank you for your answer.